# stompit is nodejs module failed to connect with error ""Unable to verify the first certificate"

Tags: node.js, stomp

I am using stompit module to connect to AMQ. If I set ssl as true then it is failing with error "Unable to verify the first certificate".
 It works if I set rejectUnauthorized as false but then code doesn't read any message from AMQ it just connects.

I tried to use certificate by setting below properties but getting same error.

```js
ssl: true,
    key:fs.readFileSync('path'),
    cert:fs.readFileSync('path'),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('path')],
```

Answer (score 0):

If your TLS (SSL) connection to AMQ is through a reverse-proxy, such as Traefik, make sure you pass the `servername` property in options. This ensure the reverse-proxy presents the correct certificate according to the servername you are attempting to access.

From Stompi's connect function's [code listings](https://github.com/gdaws/stompit/blob/500b26fe2b2f821ccbfce1a2e92c926a34e28bb1/lib/connect.js#L76) we can see that the NodeJS TLS module is used:

```
if ('ssl' in options) {
  if (typeof options.ssl === 'boolean') {
    if (options.ssl === true) {
      transportConnect = tls.connect;
    }
  }
```

The options object you pass to Stompi's connect function will be passed through to tls.connect. Node's documentation for [tls.connect](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback) mentions use of servername to ensure SNI is enabled:

> Unlike the https API, tls.connect() does not enable the SNI (Server
> Name Indication) extension by default, which may cause some servers to
> return an incorrect certificate or reject the connection altogether.
> To enable SNI, set the servername option in addition to host.